# How to fix this issue 'Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE' in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm authenticating with phone number using firebase, but getting an issue 'Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE'

Answer (score 1):

Sometime it happens. In my case I just restarted device/simulator and I worked for me. But in your case If restarting device/simulator will not work then you have to run `flutter clean`, `flutter doctor` and `invalidate caches/ restart` android studio.